# I'm in Singapore. Can I go on the same date (22nd December) from Singapore to Malaysia and Malaysia to Kolkata?

Tags: transit, international-travel, malaysia, bangladeshi-citizens

I'm a Bangladeshi citizen who has been living and working in Singapore for five years. I also have a Malaysian tourist visa. On 22nd December, I have a flight from Malaysia to Kolkata. In the morning, I'll go to Malaysia from Singapore by bus, and at night, I'll take a flight from Malaysia to Kolkata. Is there any problem?

Comment: Malaysia is a big place - where does your flight depart from?  If it's from Johor Bahru, no problems (I've done exactly that myself!).  If its from KUL, then that's a long trip just to catch a flight, although technically still no problems (outside of visas as has already been mentioned)

Comment: I'll depart from KL.

Answer (score 3):

There's no issue with this plan per se. The only question is, do you have (need?) a visa for Malaysia? I suppose you're an Indian citizen?

UPDATE:

> I have a Malaysia tourist visa. I'm a Bangladeshi citizen. I have been working in Singapore for the last 5 years

Well then, no issue at all. The Immigration officer in Malaysia might ask you how long you're staying and where. Just show the plane ticket, in that case.